# How can I send command line output to another computer?

Tags: linux, ssh, desktop-computer, remote

This sounds kind of simple but I can't really figure it out.

I have 2 computers. One is my main computer. Another is a laptop used to run business logic. It's quite loud so I put it a few meters from where I sit. But I don't like having to walk to it to check the output of the python scripts I'm running.

I'd love for there to be a way for me to see the output of the scripts on the laptop *from* my main PC.

Something like what happens when you SSH into a server and you can see the commands reflected back would be awesome but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: well, there windows does support SSH now (without the complexities of cygwin), so thats one option. another is psexec from MS/sysinternals. there is also powershell remoting, WMIC, etc. since your running python, SSH or PSEXEC seem like the best options.

Answer (score 3):

> Something like what happens when you SSH into a server

SSH into the laptop. It is not inherently limited to servers.

> But I don't like having to walk to it to check the output of the python scripts I'm running.

Run your programs inside a "multiplexer" such as tmux or screen or abduco+dvtm. They let you attach to the session from any terminal – you can start tmux on the laptop (either locally or via ssh), run something inside, then sometime later you SSH into it and do `tmux attach` to see what's happening.

Alternatively, treat your "business logic" programs as actual *services* – have them log their status into a file or syslog, and then you can either `tail thing.log` or `systemctl status mything` to peek at their most recent output.

Answer (score 0):

You may view the other computer's screen from your computer,
and even work in it remotely, by using a VNC product.

You need to install VNC in server mode on the remote computer
and install the client on your computer. You may then view
the remote computer via the VNC application on your computer.
Both functionalities of server and client are done by the same
application.

The best known is
[TeamViewer for Personal Use](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/info/free-for-personal-use/),
but there are
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/).

When using TeamViewer, the designated server shows a key that
is used on the client for gaining access. This key changes
per invocation, but can be set to never change. Doing so
means that you only need to enter it once on the client
and it will be remembered, which simplifies much the access.

Comment: It's not true that "both functionalities of server and client are done by the same application". You even clearly say yourself that you need to install a server on one computer and the client on the other. VNC server and client are two different applications. Also, TeamViewer is **not** VNC, you should not confuse one with the other.

Comment: @raj: For TeamViewer, server and client are *roles*, not different executables. The TeamViewer server can be installed as a system service, but that's another story. TeamViewer's protocol is a much-evolved VNC, which has taken elements from RDP and more and added its own, so whether it's now a VNC-variant or a new protocol is impossible to say, since it's absolutely not documented, and this may only be a play on words anyway.

Comment: So when we speak about Teamviewer, we should clearly speak about Teamviewer; and when we speak about typical VNC programs, like RealVNC, TightVNC, UltraVNC and so on, we should speak about VNC. Your answer is written in a confusing way that mixes those two. BTW. all these VNC programs have separate executables for client and server, not a single one like Teamviewer.